# How to "Autoforward" incoming BTC using Electrum

Tags: wallet, electrum, development, python, sending

We would like to generate multiple addresses in Electrum, receive BTC to these addresses on a daily basis and auto-forward them to another address automatically.
So the flow would be this:

1. BTC Sent to Electrum generated address
2. Electrum wallet balance is inquired on a timed basis (every 1 minute)
3. If Electrum wallet balance is over 0.05 BTC then it will create a new broadcast transaction to a predetermined and fixed wallet

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you could for example create a cronjob that calls a shell or python script every minute. A corresponding script would e.g. use `electrum getbalance` and `electrum payto <address> <amount>` with some additional logic to forward the funds when enough has been accumulated.

I would suggest that you avoid address-reuse by using extended pubkeys instead of fixed addresses.